# How to escape a concatenated string in html title attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

All:

I am pretty new to HTML, when I directly use something like:

```
<div title="hello&#10;world" >GO</div>
```

It works as expected which breaks the "world" into next line, but when I try:

```
var a = "&#10;";
$("#go")
    .attr("title", "hello"+ a +"world");
```

Then it will treat that line break as plain text. I wonder how can I connect string as title attribute?

Thanks

Comment: Your top tags are angularjs, reactjs and javascript, yet you're new to HTML? Please explain how that happens? haha

Comment: @dabadaba  'The more you know, the more you know you don't know.' -- Aristotle

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [escape trick mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1219983/557445) is a very common approach to dealing with encoding HTML issues. It involves creating a "phantom" `<div>` and storing your preferred HTML content within it and then using the [`text()`](http://api.jquery.com/text/) function to retrieve it :

```
// Store your new line character
var newLine = '&#10';
// Create a phantom <div> elment and set the HTML content for it
// then return the text
var title = $('<div/>').html('hello' + newLine + 'world').text();
// Finally set the attribute to the text
$("#go").attr("title", title);
```

You can [see an example of it in action here](http://jsbin.com/kemuga/edit?html,js,output) :

[image]

Answer (score 1):

jQuery handles escaping for you. You can simply do:

```
$("#go")
    .attr("title", "hello\nworld");
```